# FB SignIn Button and Google SignIn button not the same size

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uibutton, google-signin

I have to following code to implement Google and FB SignIn to my app:

```
   //GoogleSignIn

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self as GIDSignInUIDelegate
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    let GoogleLoginButton = GIDSignInButton()
    view.addSubview(GoogleLoginButton)
    GoogleLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 350, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 46)

    // FacbookLoginButton

    let FBLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(FBLoginButton)
    FBLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 410, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 46)
    FBLoginButton.delegate = self
```

For some reasons the buttons do not have the same size. Google is slightly less wide and high. Can somebody help?

Comment: create custom buttons and set image same to button as google and Facebook has....and implement your logic on button click...simple...

Comment: Try to set Custom images for google & Facebook